# SemanticUI Accordion - Second level of nested accordion not opening properly

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

Second level of nested accordion is not opening properly. Is this my fault or Semantic bug?

Click on 1 then on 1.1:

http://embed.plnkr.co/OY1Wfk1bizsmqXqRmOVF/preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nested accordions should not have class `.ui`.  Consider that in Semantic, generally, the `.ui` class is reserved for component top level, and children elements (`.item`,`.description`,`.title`) inherit basis their top-level component.

Comment: Accordingly to your answer @james-holland I removed repeated `.ui` classes so only top level accordion has one now and changed selector for initializing accordion to `.ui.accordion`. It works OK now. Thx!